# Boost Socket/Acceptor cannot listen/connect on same port?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, network-programming, boost-asio

I am a bit new to Boost, but I am trying to create a Server that can accept connections from a client on a given port. This Server should also be able to write to the client on the same port.

However, when I attempt to implement both using `acceptor_.bind()`/`acceptor_.listen()` as well as `socket_.connect(*iterator)` the `async_accept()` fails with an invalid function error.

If I only use `acceptor_.bind()`, `acceptor_.listen()` I am able to write to the socket (from the Server to the Client) using `async_write()`.

If I only use `socket_.connect()` (but comment out the `acceptor_.bind()`, `acceptor_.listen()`) I am able to read from the socket (data sent from Client to Server) using `async_read_some()`.

Do I need to create a separate socket object or choose another port? I have reuse address enabled set to True.

Comment: rather than describe your code with words, post [complete code](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you trying to `connect()` to a client that is already connected to your server?  Just write to the existing socket that was accepted for that connection.

If you must `connect()` a second connection to a client (for example, like the FTP protocol does for data transfers), then don't specify a port to bind that socket to.  Let the OS decide a suitable port to use.

Comment: You were absolutely right! Didn't need to listen and connect, just connected and async read/write working fine. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be you haven't grasped some basic concepts of network programming, this is unrelated to boost or the Asio library. Generally speaking, servers invoke `accept()` and clients invoke `connect()`. The asio examples show this in detail, see

- [async tcp echo server](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp)
- [blocking tcp echo client](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/blocking_tcp_echo_client.cpp)

And note that the server invokes

- `async_accept()`
- `async_read_some()`
- `async_write()`

whereas the client invokes

- `connect()`
- `write()`
- `read()`